# Calculating the perimeter of a Right Trapezoid

Tags: c

I am not sure what i am missing from this code.

I am creating a tool where you can calculate the perimeter of a right trapezoid within C programming and the perimeter line keeps presenting an error.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
   #include<math.h>
   int main () { 

 /* variable definition: */
float baseA, baseB, height, perimeter;
/* Prompt user for baseA */
printf("Enter the first base of the trapezoid: \n");
// Input the base
scanf("%f", &baseA);

/* Prompt user for baseB */
printf("Enter the second base of the trapezoid: \n");
// Input the baseB
scanf("%f", &baseB);

/* Prompt user for height */
printf("Enter the height of the trapezoid: \n");
// Input the height
scanf("%f", &height);

 // Calculate the Perimeter
 perimeter = baseA + baseB + height + sqrt(height*height + (baseB – 
 baseA)*(baseB – baseA) );
 // Print the result
 printf("Perimeter is: %f\n", perimeter);

 return 0;}`
```

User should be able to input any numbers and calculate the result of a Right trapezoid with the pythagorean theorem in C Code format.

Comment: What error is it presenting? Could you be more explicit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are not using the `-` character for division. I copied your code and got the error:

```
error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers
    perimeter = baseA + baseB + height + sqrt(height*height + (baseB – baseA)*(baseB - baseA) );
```

I just swapped out your `-` with `-` and it worked.

Comment: I cannot believe it was that simple. smh. well now i feel like a idiot. Thank you Juilan. i still haven't figured out to read error pages well.

Comment: glad I could help. btw it'd be nice if you clicked the check next to my answer :)

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I am new too this website also.